# Unbind a jquery behavior on removeClass

Tags: jquery, css

I wrote a simple jquery function that run a particular action clicking on a div.
After the click, this function loads another div like the first one, if you click on this second div the function load a third one and so on...
All works right but even if I remove the "active" class from every clicked div, if you click on a div already clicked it fire the function again.

How can I remove the behavior on the div already clicked so that they stop loading other divs?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `$.fn.off` is your friend. http://api.jquery.com/off/ But it is hard to say more without your code.

Comment: Your best bet is to delegate click event to any closest common ancestor. This way, the selector would be processed (filtered) on the fly

Answer (score 1):

The event are attached to elements not with selector, so once the event is attached it doesn't matter if you remove the CSS class.

You need to use [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) delegated-events approach, when manipulation selector (like removing and adding classes).

*General Syntax*

```
$(staticParentElement).on('event','selector',callback_function)
```

Comment: Ya, and for a working example: `$(document).on('click','div.active', function(){...});`

Answer (score 0):

mark clicked or only bind event to active elements

```
$(document).on('click', '.selector:not(.clicked)', function(){
    //add element
    $(this).addClass('clicked'); // do not trigger event again
});

$(document).on('click', '.selector.active', function(){
    //add element with active class
    $(this).removeClass('active'); // do not trigger event again
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the unbind function on $(this) to remove the function behavior to the clicked element :)

Thanks to everyone!